# Android - listView Problems -

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I created an app that it should work as a telephone directory. Firstly I enter the data, then save, and finally I should see a list (listView) with my saved data.
But I don't see no list, although the data are present in the database. I inserted an "else" statement for to control if the db is full.

MainActivity.java

```
        if(gridList.size()!=0){
        Log.i("PROVA", "size: " + gridList.size());
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                id_grid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_grid);
                String id_gridValue = id_grid.getText().toString();

                Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplication(),EditSheet.class);
                theIntent.putExtra("id_grid", id_gridValue);
                startActivity(theIntent);


                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,gridList, R.layout.grid_entry, new String[]{
                        "id_grid", "site"}, new int[] {R.id.id_grid, R.id.edit_site});

                /*String[] values  = new String[]{"id_grid", "edit_site", "edit_tab"};
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        values);*/
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });


    }  else  {
        Log.i("PROVA", "size = 0");
    }
```

and the result is this:

[

> I/PROVA: size: 1
>   W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fa218cf5a00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7fa218e4dc00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7fa21bc653a0
>   Application terminated.

[image: Image 1]

This is the layout of the activity_main:

[image: activity_main layout]

I believe it's a list display issue.

Comment: it is not a good idea to put setadapter inside empty listview

Comment: Hi uguboz, where I should add it?

Comment: after the setOnclicklistener is fine

Answer (score 0):

try to use

> `listView.notifyDataSetChanged();`